# Print out one of 2 post category

Tags: posts, categories

I've been trying for quite a few hours to get something to print out in loop:
post has 2 categories, one of them is `prace` (slug) and I need the other one printed. If it isn't too much to ask.

Tried just about everything with categories I could but can't get any further due my lack of knowledge of working with arrays in PHP.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Do you mean you just want to print (echo) the categories a post belongs to? And do you mean categories, or do you mean terms?

Comment: Yes print (echo), post categories. Not sure what terms are but I select the two post categories when writing a post.

Comment: Tried the codex? [get_the_term_list](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_the_term_list)

Comment: `var_dump(get_the_category_list( ',', the_ID()));` gives me `64string(253) "Práce,Propagačná grafika"` I don't know how to get the Propagačná grafika out of there, or remove everything except the categories and then the Práce one to finish with the other.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand your requirements correctly:

```
$terms = wp_get_post_terms( $post->ID, 'category' );
echo $terms[1]->name;
```

You can see what other values are returned by `var_dump`ing `$terms`. The above assumes that you are using the category taxonomy.

Comment: Thanks so much, could you explain to me how $post->ID works? I thought that $name are vars and you need to define them.

Comment: $post->ID is simply the ID of the post you are on, and is supplied by WP. See the codex for the rest: [wp_get_post_terms()](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_get_post_terms).